# Fixtures don't work with Synfony 2.4.1

Tags: doctrine-orm, fixtures

First of all, I'm sorry if I did not explain well, English is not my native language

I have the following problem, I am making a test application in Symfony (2.3 at first) and also decided to upgrade Symfony version 2.4 with Composer. That gave me the following error when I try to load the Fixtures (php app / console doctrine: fixtures: load):

```
[InvalidArgumentException]                                                                                
  Could not find any fixtures to load in:                                                                   

  - /var/www/miweb/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/DataFixtures/ORM               
  - /var/www/miweb/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/SecurityBundle/DataFixtures/ORM                
  - /var/www/miweb/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/DataFixtures/ORM                    
  - /var/www/miweb/vendor/symfony/monolog-bundle/Symfony/Bundle/MonologBundle/DataFixtures/ORM              
  - /var/www/miweb/vendor/symfony/swiftmailer-bundle/Symfony/Bundle/SwiftmailerBundle/DataFixtures/ORM      
  - /var/www/miweb/vendor/symfony/assetic-bundle/Symfony/Bundle/AsseticBundle/DataFixtures/ORM              
  - /var/www/miweb/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/Doctrine/Bundle/DoctrineBundle/DataFixtures/ORM          
  - /var/www/miweb/vendor/sensio/framework-extra-bundle/Sensio/Bundle/FrameworkExtraBundle/DataFixtures/ORM 
  - /var/www/miweb/src/Web/MainBundle/DataFixtures/ORM                                                      
  - /var/www/miweb/src/Web/UserBundle/DataFixtures/ORM                                                      
  - /var/www/miweb/src/Web/BlogBundle/DataFixtures/ORM                                                      
  - /var/www/miweb/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle/Doctrine/Bundle/FixturesBundle/DataFixtures/ORM 
  - /var/www/miweb/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/WebProfilerBundle/DataFixtures/ORM             
  - /var/www/miweb/vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle/DataFixtures/ORM      
  - /var/www/miweb/vendor/sensio/generator-bundle/Sensio/Bundle/GeneratorBundle/DataFixtures/ORM
```

In addition, before the error shows me the source code for all fixtures that I created, which should not happen.

I also tried to make it from scratch, Symfony 2.4 was downloaded from the web, then I followed exactly the steps in the official documentation (http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html) and happen the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using older version of doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle.

For example this version is working for me in Symfony 2.4:

> dev-master#512fc0fa1d0ce7bdcc6a0a91812eb531f20e0828

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll try that, but Im new with Symfony and don't sure how a particular version is installed.